# Can we say the doctor looks at ill people or helps ill people

Tags: exam-questions

> I can get the write answer the right answer for this following question. Read carefully.
> The doctor_______ ill people.
>
> A.looks at
> B.speaks to
> C.helps
> D.serves drink

Comment: Welcome to ELL, David.  This appears to be a test question searching for an answer.  We ask that your question include what your thinking is regarding the question, what possible solutions you might have considered, and why you may still have the question.

Answer (score 2):

A, B, and C would all be grammatically valid and make sense.

"The doctor looks at ill people." There's a doctor, and there are ill people, and the doctor looks at the ill people. From the fact that it says "doctor" I'd assume this means he looks to try to understand their illnesses. If it said, "The artist looks at pretty girls" I'd assume it means because he is considering painting them. Etc.

"The doctor speaks to ill people." Same idea. He talks to them. Again, because it says "doctor" I'd assume that he talks to them about their health problems.

"The doctor helps ill people." Presumably meaning that he provides medical care.

"The doctor serves drink ill people" fails for (at least) three reasons. One, it is not grammatically correct. "Drink" here is a noun. A noun cannot take an object. Only verbs can take objects. Like in the previous case, "The doctor helps ill people", "helps" is a verb, and the direct object of that verb is "ill people". Here "serves" is a verb and the direct object of "serves" is "drink", but there's no apparent role in the sentence for "ill people". You could turn it into an indirect object and say, "The doctor serves drinks TO ill people."

Two, as "drink" is singular, it should have an article. Like, "The doctor serves a drink to an ill person." More likely, it should be plural. "The doctor serves drinks to ill people."

Three, the sentence is unlikely. Doctors do not normally serve drinks. We'd expect a waiter or a hostess to serve drinks, not a doctor. It is possible, of course. I could imagine someone saying, "The rich man treated the doctor like a servant. The doctor served him drinks, polished his shoes, and fetched his mail." Or some such. Unlikely but possible.

Comment: "Doctors do not normally serve drinks. We'd expect a waiter or a hostess to serve drinks, not a doctor." Or a nurse, though you probably wouldn't call it "serving drinks" in a medical context.

Comment: "Looks at ill people" is unlikely - we'd say "examines ill people".  So we can reasonably surmise that "helps ill people" is the answer the OP is most likely to be looking for.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes. A nurse might bring meals and drinks to a patient in a hospital, but we don't normally say "the nurse was serving drinks". At least I never said that. I'd have to ask one of my medical friends how hospital workers describe it. Do they say, "I have to serve breakfast to the patient in room 239"? I don't know.

Comment: @rjpond I'd agree to an extent. It's common for doctors to say,  "Let me look at your ankle" or whatever the area of the complaint is. "Look at a patient"? Probably less common than "examine a patient". Doctors often say they "see a patient".